# how to add new column in pg_class for object creation date dumping

Tags: postgresql, auditing, system-tables

I want to create a column in pg_class for object creation dumping but I am not able to add.
I am using below query:
ALTER TABLE pg_catalog.pg_class ADD COLUMN relcreated TIMESTAMP;

when I run this query I'm getting below error:
ERROR:  permission denied: "pg_class" is a system catalog
SQL state: 42501
Please suggest any way for object creation time dumping. This is quite important for me for auditing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

That's a system table. You can't just fiddle with them.

You might find [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-matrix.html) useful though.

Answer (score 0):

Set `log_statement = 'ddl'` and get the information from the log file.

You cannot change a catalog like that “ that would require non-trivial changes to the PostgreSQL code, and you'd lose the information during every upgrade.

Comment: I did this earlier but that's not working. I have created a user and checked.

Comment: It is working quite well. You must have made a mistake.